# How to set an ID to a http inbound gateway (DSL-style)?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

In my Spring Boot application, I have the following inbound-gateway (Java DSL):

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow upperCaseFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(
                        Http.inboundGateway("/conversions/upperCase")
                        .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.POST).consumes("text/plain"))
                        .requestPayloadType(String.class)
                        .id("upperCaseGateway")
                )
                .<String>handle((p, h) -> p.toUpperCase())
                .get();
    }
```

The **.id("upperCaseGateway")**, I assume, is the part where an **"id"** is being set to the gateway.

On the other hand, I am trying to implement another HTTP inbound gateway in a slightly different DSL style as follows:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpGetFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGetGate()).channel("httpGetChannel").handle("personEndpoint", "get").get();
    }

@Bean
    public MessagingGatewaySupport httpGetGate() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway handler = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();
        handler.setRequestMapping(createMapping(new HttpMethod[]{HttpMethod.GET}, "/persons/{personId}"));
        handler.setPayloadExpression(parser().parseExpression("#pathVariables.personId"));
        handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper());

        return handler;
    }

@Bean
    public HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper() {
        return new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
    }
```

**My question:**
In the 2nd style of creating the http inbound gateway, how do I set an id to the gateway with value as "**getPersonsGateway**"?
I see that in the 1st style, this is possible with a simple **.id("upperCaseGateway")** call.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` is simply a bean name; for composite components (consumers), it is the consumer endpoint bean name and the message handler gets `<id>.handler`.

For simple message-drive components such as the http inbound adapter it's simply the bean name. So name your bean appropriately.

Either

```
@Bean("upperCaseGateway")
public MessagingGatewaySupport httpGetGate() {
```

or, simply

```
@Bean
public MessagingGatewaySupport upperCaseGateway() {
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Gary!